# Spring JUnit: How to Mock autowired component in autowired component

Tags: java, spring, junit, dependency-injection

I've got a Spring component I'd like to test and this component has an autowired attribute which I need to change for the purpose of unit testing. The problem is, that the class uses the autowired component inside the post-construct method so I'm not able to replace it(i.e. via ReflectionTestUtils) before it's actually used.

How should I do that?

This is the class I want to test:

```
@Component
public final class TestedClass{

    @Autowired
    private Resource resource;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init(){
        //I need this to return different result
        resource.getSomething();
    }
}
```

And this is the base of a test case:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations= "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
public class TestedClassTest{

    @Autowired
    private TestedClass instance;

    @Before
    private void setUp(){
        //this doesn't work because it's executed after the bean is instantiated
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(instance, "resource", new Resource("something"));
    }
}
```

Is there some way to replace the resource with something else before the postconstruct method is invoked? Like to tell Spring JUnit runner to autowire different instance?

Comment: Depends on the Spring version you are using - there might be different answers. Refer to: https://dzone.com/articles/mockbean-spring-boots-missing-ingredient

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can provide a new testContext.xml in which the `@Autowired` bean you define is of the type you need for your test.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I did and is working. I'm just wondering if there's a way to do that without writing new context(although I only imported the old one and overrode the bean i needed)

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj try using the @Qualifier("myAlternateBean") then, it should solve your problem

Comment: That's a misunderstanding. Your suggestion works. It's just not exactly what I was  looking for. I'll use it until I find something else. Thanks

Comment: If you are using autowiring in tests then having test specific contexts is normal so I wouldn't worry about looking for something better. The only other possibilities are to override init (which means it can't be private) or manually wire your beans for the test.

Comment: @ph. How to do it in Spring-Boot where there are no .xml files. Do I have to create a configuration file for the test?

Answer (score 75):

You could use [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito). I am not sure with `PostConstruct` specifically, but this generally works:

```
// Create a mock of Resource to change its behaviour for testing
@Mock
private Resource resource;

// Testing instance, mocked `resource` should be injected here 
@InjectMocks
@Resource
private TestedClass testedClass;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    // Initialize mocks created above
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    // Change behaviour of `resource`
    when(resource.getSomething()).thenReturn("Foo");   
}
```

Comment: I've tried exactly this, but the ```PostConstruct``` is still executed before the ```setUp()``` method.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj, another chance is with `@BeforeClass` instead of `@Before`. Not sure how `initMocks` works with this though.

Comment: That was my idea too, but ```MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(Object o)``` requires an instance of the test class.

Comment: Or with new TestUnit5 just use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` before your test class.

Answer (score 32):

Spring Boot 1.4 introduced testing annotation called [`@MockBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans). So now mocking and spying on Spring beans is natively supported by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 9):

I created [blog post on the topic](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/). It contains also link to Github repository with working example.

The trick is using test configuration, where you override original spring bean with fake one. You can use `@Primary` and `@Profile` annotations for this trick.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I need!

Answer (score 8):

You can override bean definitions with mocks with spring-reinject https://github.com/sgri/spring-reinject/

Answer (score 5):

Another approach in integration testing is to define a new Configuration class and provide it as your `@ContextConfiguration`. Into the configuration you will be able to mock your beans and also you must define all types of beans which you are using in test/s flow.
To provide an example :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MockTest{
 @Configuration
 static class ContextConfiguration{
 // ... you beans here used in test flow
 @Bean
    public MockMvc mockMvc() {
        return MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(/*you can declare your controller beans defines on top*/)
                .addFilters(/*optionally filters*/).build();
    }
 //Defined a mocked bean
 @Bean
    public MyService myMockedService() {
        return Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
    }
 }

 @Autowired
 private MockMvc mockMvc;

 @Autowired
 MyService myMockedService;

 @Before
 public void setup(){
  //mock your methods from MyService bean 
  when(myMockedService.myMethod(/*params*/)).thenReturn(/*my answer*/);
 }

 @Test
 public void test(){
  //test your controller which trigger the method from MyService
  MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get(CONTROLLER_URL)).andReturn();
  // do your asserts to verify
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Junit5, you can mock using:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class MytestClass {

@Mock
MyInjectedSevice myInjservice;

@InjectMock
MyService myservice;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
import org.junit.Before;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

@Mock
    private IMyInterface yInterface;

    @InjectMocks
    @Resource
    ResourceDependant resourceDependant = new resourceDependant();


    @Before
    public void initMocksForInjection() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }
```