# Mocking class with @PostConstruct causes initialization failure

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I've a java program that looks like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractA {
  @Autowired
  protected B b;
}

@Component
public class A extends AbstractA {
  private C c;

  @PostConstruct
  public void initilizeC() {
    c = b.getInternalMember();
  }
}

@Component
public class D {
  @Autowired
  private A a;
}

@Component
public class E {
  @Autowired
  private D d;
}
```

My test classes looks like this:

```
@ContextConfiguration(location = {"file:unit-test.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ETest {
  //class E(being tested) internally uses method of D
  @Autowired
  private A a;

  @Test
  public void methodOfETest() {
    Mockito.when(a.methodOfC(anyInt())).thenReturn(1);
  }

  @After
  public void resetMocks() {
    Mockito.reset(a);
  }
}
```

My spring file (only capturing the bean initializations)

```
  <bead id="b" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg="classpath to B" />
  </bean>

  <bead id="a" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg="classpath to A" />
  </bean>
```

My unit tests are failing because of the following exception:

```
    [junit] Failed to load ApplicationContext
     [junit] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
     [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'e': Injection of autowired dependencies
 failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
 autowire field: protected class-path.D class-path.E.d; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'd': Injection of autowired dependencies
 failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
 autowire field: private class-path.a class-path.d.a; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'a': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:838)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
     [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
 autowire field: protected class-path.D class-path.E.d; nested
 exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'd': Injection of autowired dependencies
 failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
 autowire field: private class-path.a class-path.d.a; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'a': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
     [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'd': Injection of autowired dependencies
 failed; nested exception is
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
 autowire field: private class-path.a class-path.d.a; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'a': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
     [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
 autowire field: private class-path.a class-path.d.a; nested exception
 is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'a': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
     [junit] Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
 creating bean with name 'a': Invocation of init method failed; nested
 exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
     [junit] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     [junit]     at class-path.A.initializeC(A.java:64)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:354)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
     [junit]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133)
```

As per the comment, I am able to use @Qualifier and get the test case working. But I'm still interested in understanding how @PostConstruct works while mocking.

Please can you help me find answers to the following questions?

1. How do @PostConstruct annotated methods work while mocking?
2. In my case, classes A, B & C belong to a different package. Hence, I need to mock them. 
   3.1. Why isn't it sufficient to just mock A?
   3.2. Why should I understand the internals of A and mock the underlying/dependent classes as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JUnit: How to Mock autowired component in autowired component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299513/spring-junit-how-to-mock-autowired-component-in-autowired-component)

Comment: Hi Gergely, the link actually did help. I am now able to get the tests running. But, I am still looking to understand how @PostConstruct methods get initialized.

Comment: "classpath to B" : I think you mean class name of B?

Comment: Hi Adrian, no. It is 'classpath to B'

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to so if you mock before context load. something like this

```
public static class ContextLoader extends GenericXmlContextLoader {
    @Override
    protected void customizeContext(GenericApplicationContext context) {
        super.customizeContext(context);
        // Add mock for A in context here
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sourabh, I didn't understand your answer. Please can you explain in more detail?