# How do you mock external dependencies in spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit4, functional-testing

I have a requirement to test a SpringBoot application where I run the tests against the end point (for now, locally).

There is one call from a service to external service (`s3`), and I just need to mock this, so that we don't do a live call to `s3` from our test.

I use Mockito for mocking.

The call stack:

```
Controller -service

                   -external service.
```

From my test, I just hit the end point url (`localhost:8080/actions/domyjob`)

This is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/myjob")
public class MyController{

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/doJobInMyService", method = POST)
    public void doJobInMyService(){
        myService.doMyJob()
    }

}
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private s3Client AmazonS3Client;

     doMyJob() {
    s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest());
}
}
```

If you see, if I want to test the entire flow, by calling `localhost:8080/myjob/doJobInMyService` and just mock `s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest())`, so that external calls to `s3` is not done.

Tried this, but I had still no luck:

```
@ActiveProfiles("MyTestConfig")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest extends BaseTest {
    @Autowired
    private AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client;

    @Test
    public void testMyResponse() {
        try {
            Mockito.when(amazonS3Client.putObject(anyObject())).thenReturn(new PutObjectResult());
            assertNotNull(getMyClient().doMyJob());
        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}

@Profile("MyTestConfig")
@Configuration
public class MyTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public AmazonS3Client amazonS3Client() {
        return Mockito.mock(AmazonS3Client.class);
    }
```

Comment: Use Mockito to create a mock of the client that calls the service.

Comment: We just hit the endpoint of the application through tests. Not really sure how spring would inject the mocked client during testing and real client for application purpose.

Comment: I don't have Spring inject mocks when I test.  I write JUnit tests and do the injection manually using ctor injection.  No need for Spring there.

Comment: Do you invoke the end point while doing so? An example would be great

Comment: No, I invoke the client and tell it to return what I know the endpoint would give me for that input.  That's what mocking is.

Comment: Could you share a sample test code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299513/spring-junit-how-to-mock-autowired-component-in-autowired-component can be a solution?

Comment: Can't you add some test configuration that creates a MyService from Mockito.mock ? Or even an s3Client? With profiles you can further control the whole test/not test thing.

Comment: Dzmitry - i think that's more of a unit test. But i will look into it in detail.

Comment: Florian-Profiling is something i was thinking. Any example where i can override the external client to use a mock via an integration test would be really great.

Answer (score 2):

Since Spring Boot 1.4.x, there is Mockito mocking of Spring beans natively supported via annotation `@MockBean`. See [this section of Spring Boot docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I created [blog post on the topic](https://lkrnac.net/blog/2015/12/mock-spring-bean-v2/). It contains also link to Github repository with working example.

The trick is using test configuration, where you override original spring bean (e.g. `s3Client` in your case) with fake one. You can use `@Primary` and `@Profile` annotations for this trick.

Comment: I tried,but no luck.Have updated my approach using your solution in the post.

Comment: @Pete, could you please be more specific? I don't see the problem in FF not Chrome.

Comment: @luboskrnac, It wasn't working yesterday, but today it's fine, so no problem

Comment: yeah, might have been Cloudflare hiccup.