# Unsatisfied dependency expressed while injecting Bean in Unit test

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, dependency-injection, spring-test

Here is my test code

```
package com.tasks;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = ITest.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ITest {

  @Inject
  IAccessor iAccessor1;

  @Test
  public void testRun() {
  }

  @Configuration
  @Profile("test")
  @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses{com.tasks.ITest.class})
  public static class ITestConfiguration{

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public IAccessor iDataAccessor(){
        IAccessor iAccessor =  mock(IAccessor.class);
        return iAccessor;
    }
  }
}
```

I tried @Autowired instead of Inject, but got the same error.

In my class under test I have

```
@Component
public class ISync {

  @Inject
  private IAccessor iAccessor;


  public int someMethod(){

    iAccessor.someOtherMethod(); //want to mock out

  }
}
```

So I want to inject a mocked up value. However I get a depenedency error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.database.iAccessor1' available:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
>   Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

It works generally for me, but I do not know what is the problem here in this particular case.
I want the answer to what is the problem with my solution.

I already tried :
[Spring JUnit: How to Mock autowired component in autowired component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299513/spring-junit-how-to-mock-autowired-component-in-autowired-component)
1) The accepted answer is using testContext.xml
I do not use any xml.
2) I used @MockBean but I started getting other error.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.mockito.Mockito.mockingDetails(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/mockito/MockingDetails;

TO rectify it I bumped the version of mockito-all 1.9.0 to 1.9.5 (though I don't know why is it trying to find it).

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.getMockSettings(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;

I got it working by bumping the version to 1.0.19. But the value in the class under test was still null. So this didn't work for me.

I want to know what is the problem with my original solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring JUnit: How to Mock autowired component in autowired component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299513/spring-junit-how-to-mock-autowired-component-in-autowired-component)

Comment: also just look at the 'Related' questions on the left, this is not a new question.

Comment: Why do you want to inject a 'mocked' up value? Why not just use a mock via @Mock or mock(...)?

Comment: @tkruse I want to know the problem in my solution. Also the current solution required me to bump up the version. If I want to stay on the same version, I'll need my solution to work.

Comment: @SeanCarroll Mock creates a mock but does not injects it to the autowired property which would be null upon calling the function of that class.

Comment: Thats my point. Why do you need to autowire the property which is just the mock? Why not just use the mock directly? What is the benefit of the indirection of injecting the mock in what you have provided.

Comment: I do not send it as a parameter of the method call, how would the Mocked value reach the actual class?

Comment: Sorry, solution does not work, as the mocked value does not reach the class under test and is null!!

Comment: I dont think you've provided the details you are talking about. Your test method is empty and iAccessor1 isn't used in what you've provided

Comment: If you're attempting to use mock in the class you should also look at MockitoJUnitRunner

Comment: I think @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) I do not need MockitoJUnitRunner.

Comment: Thats used for Spring's TestContext which per my understanding is different

Comment: It's giving me an error even with an empty method. It should have initialized the iAccessor because there is a static class providing the Bean. That should be enough. It's a working code(with the error).

Comment: I have a Bean, so I will need to use it in my implementation. I am pretty sure about that.

Comment: Yes but thats different than what my suggestion was. I'd be happy to talk more in chat

Comment: Sorry. We're talking about different things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162641/discussion-between-bhavya-arora-and-sean-carroll).

Comment: In all the answers to all similar questions, do not just look at the 'accepted' answer, but look at all the answers, the highest voted one, and the newest one.

Answer (score 0):

Make your class `ISync` to accept `IAccessor` in the constructor.
Then in the test you will be able to pass a mock `IAccessor` to it and then verify that `someOtherMethod()` was called on your `IAccessor` mock.

Answer (score 0):

The function name for the

```
@Bean
@Primary
public IAccessor iDataAccessor(){
    IAccessor iAccessor =  mock(IAccessor.class);
    return iAccessor;
}
```

It started working as soon as I changed it to iAccessor1().
making it

`public IAccessor iAccessor1()`