# How to mock ObjectMapper with mokito?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with mocking an ObjectMapper bean with mokito.

My class containing the ObjectMapper :

```
public class ServiceParent{

        @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper objectMapper;

        public void someMethod(){
        ...
        Map<String, String> mapResponse = objectMapper.readValue("some json", new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});

}

Other class extending previous one

public class ServiceChild extends ServiceParent{
...

}
```

My test class :

```
@SpringBootTest
public class TestService{
       @Mock
       ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceChild  serviceChild;

 @Test
 public void test(){
    Map<String, String> mapResponse=new HashMap<String, String>();
        mapResponse.put("access_token", "token_bouhon");
        Mockito.when(objectMapper.readValue(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Class.class))).thenReturn(mapResponse);

}
```

So when I debug this, in ServiceParent, objectMapper isn't null but readValue(...) return null.

Do you have an idea on how to return the correct mocked object?

Thanks

Comment: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299513/spring-junit-how-to-mock-autowired-component-in-autowired-component

Comment: Change your `@Mock ObjectMapper` to `@MockBean ObjectMapper`

Comment: Also, your code passes a TypeReference as second argument, but you're mocking with a Class as second argument.

Comment: Also, since you are starting a spring context you should `@Inject` your `ServiceChild` as a bean and delete the `@InjectMocks` annotation.

Comment: Even with @MockBean objectMapper.readValues(...) returns null.

Comment: @JBNizet Actually that was the problem here. I try to mock with Mockito.<TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>>any() instead of Mockito.any(Class.class)) and it works! Thanks!

Comment: @Raikyn I am having the same issue, could you please post the full answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same NPE with the objectmapper. This issue is resolved after adding ,
my test class has class level annotation with

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

and the fix

```
 @Before
    public void setupBefore() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    }
```

Comment: This sounds ... weird. The whole point of the @ SpringBootTest annotation is to establish a setup where all the spring annotations work as if it were a production setup. Your suggestion here is addressing a very basic problem when people are doing mockito unit tests ... without Spring being involved. I really doubt that this answer actually works for the given spring boot context.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/mockito-injectmocks-mocks-dependency-injection
@GhostCat. I have referred this , in our code , we have constructor based injection , setter and field based in single class , now i cleared up those  into constructor alone , i was facing this issue in junit 5.

Answer (score 0):

`@Mock` creates a new mock. It's equivalent to calling `mock(SomeClass.class)`

`@MockBean` creates a mock, like `@Mock`, but also replaces any bean already in the application context with the same type with that mock. So any code which `Autowire`s that bean will get the mock.

You need to use `@MockBean`

Comment: Even with @MockBean it returns null. Also, why should I use it instead of @Mock? My point is just mocking this particular bean